# Aplico setText a un Qlabel de PyQt4 en Python y no modifica el texto en la etiqueta sino que le superpone el cambio

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyqt

Cuando corro el código aparece una MainWindow en el cual hay dos radioButton, si presiono alguno de los dos, un widget contenedor sera adicionado y mostrado  en la ventana principal, en el habrá varios objetos de entre los cuales me importan las etiquetas presentes, las cuales poseerán un texto definido, de volver a presionar alguno de los radioButton un nuevo texto debería aparecer en  las etiquetas sin embargo no es eso lo que esta ocurriendo, lo que sucede es que el texto anterior es conservado y el nuevo se le superpone, es decir los textos se están solapando y el resultado final es un texto incomprensible al usuario. Como puedo lograr que se exhiba el nuevo texto borrando el anterior, ese es mi problema.

```
import sys
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
import ui_adap1stubnew12

class stub1(QMainWindow,ui_adap1stubnew12.Ui_adap1s):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QWidget.__init__(self,parent)
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.i=False
        self.band1=False
        self.band2=False

        self.connect(self.radioboton1, SIGNAL("clicked()"),self.llamarimpedancia)
        self.connect(self.radioboton2, SIGNAL("clicked()"),self.llamaradmitancia)

        def llamarimpedancia(self):        
        if self.i==False :
            print(self.i)
            self.band1=True
            self.myapp3=self.contenido(self.grupo)
            self.myapp3.show()
            self.i=True
        elif self.band2==True :
            print(self.i)
            self.band2=False
            self.band1=True
            self.myapp3=self.contenido(self.grupo)
            self.myapp3.show()
        else:
            print(self.i)
            self.band1=True
            self.myapp3=self.contenido(self.grupo)
            self.myapp3.show()#sin este comando no es mostrado en la ventana el nuevo widget

    def llamaradmitancia(self):
        if self.i==False :
            print(self.i)
            self.band2=True
            self.myapp3=self.contenido(self.grupo)
            self.myapp3.show()
            self.i=True
        elif self.band1==True :
            print(self.i)
            self.band1=False
            self.band2=True
            self.myapp3=self.contenido(self.grupo)
            self.myapp3.show()
        else:
            print(self.i)
            self.band2=True
            self.myapp3=self.contenido(self.grupo)
            self.myapp3.show()#sin este comando no es mostrado en la ventana el nuevo widget


    def contenido(self, parent):

        self.frame8 = QFrame(parent)
        self.frame8.setGeometry(QRect(11,110,214,374))
        #self.widget.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("widget"))
        self.verticalLayout_5 = QVBoxLayout(self.frame8)
        #self.verticalLayout_5.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("verticalLayout_5"))
        spacerItem2 = QSpacerItem(20, 18, QSizePolicy.Minimum,QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        self.verticalLayout_5.addItem(spacerItem2)
        self.verticalLayout_2 = QVBoxLayout()
        #self.verticalLayout_2.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("verticalLayout_2"))
        self.horizontalLayout_9 = QHBoxLayout()
         #self.horizontalLayout_9.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("horizontalLayout_9"))
        spacerItem3 = QSpacerItem(40, 20, QSizePolicy.Expanding,QSizePolicy.Minimum)
        self.horizontalLayout_9.addItem(spacerItem3)
        self.etiqueta2 = QLabel(self.frame8)
        self.etiqueta2.setScaledContents(False)
        self.etiqueta2.setWordWrap(False)
        #self.etiqueta2.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("etiqueta2"))
        self.horizontalLayout_9.addWidget(self.etiqueta2)
        spacerItem4 = QSpacerItem(40, 20, QSizePolicy.Expanding,QSizePolicy.Minimum)
        self.horizontalLayout_9.addItem(spacerItem4)
        self.verticalLayout_2.addLayout(self.horizontalLayout_9)
        self.horizontalLayout_3 = QHBoxLayout()
        #self.horizontalLayout_3.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("horizontalLayout_3"))
        self.etiqueta3 = QLabel(self.frame8)
        #self.etiqueta3.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("etiqueta3"))
        self.horizontalLayout_3.addWidget(self.etiqueta3)
        self.lineEdit1 = QLineEdit(self.frame8)
        self.lineEdit1.setMaximumSize(QSize(90, 16777215))
        #self.lineEdit1.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("lineEdit1"))
        self.horizontalLayout_3.addWidget(self.lineEdit1)
        self.etiqueta4 = QLabel(self.frame8)
        #self.etiqueta4.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("etiqueta4"))
        self.horizontalLayout_3.addWidget(self.etiqueta4)
        self.verticalLayout_2.addLayout(self.horizontalLayout_3)
        self.horizontalLayout_4 = QHBoxLayout()
        #self.horizontalLayout_4.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("horizontalLayout_4"))
        self.etiqueta5 = QLabel(self.frame8)
        #self.etiqueta5.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("etiqueta5"))
        self.horizontalLayout_4.addWidget(self.etiqueta5)
        self.lineEdit2 = QLineEdit(self.frame8)
        self.lineEdit2.setMaximumSize(QSize(90, 16777215))
        #self.lineEdit2.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("lineEdit2"))
        self.horizontalLayout_4.addWidget(self.lineEdit2)
        self.etiqueta6 = QLabel(self.frame8)
        #self.etiqueta6.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("etiqueta6"))
        self.horizontalLayout_4.addWidget(self.etiqueta6)
        self.verticalLayout_2.addLayout(self.horizontalLayout_4)
        self.verticalLayout_5.addLayout(self.verticalLayout_2)
        spacerItem5 = QSpacerItem(20, 13, QSizePolicy.Minimum,QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        self.verticalLayout_5.addItem(spacerItem5)
        self.verticalLayout_3 = QVBoxLayout()
        #self.verticalLayout_3.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("verticalLayout_3"))
        self.horizontalLayout_10 = QHBoxLayout()
        #self.horizontalLayout_10.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("horizontalLayout_10"))
        spacerItem6 = QSpacerItem(40, 20, QSizePolicy.Expanding,QSizePolicy.Minimum)
        self.horizontalLayout_10.addItem(spacerItem6)
        self.etiqueta7 = QLabel(self.frame8)
        #self.etiqueta7.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("etiqueta7"))
        self.horizontalLayout_10.addWidget(self.etiqueta7)
        spacerItem7 = QSpacerItem(40, 20, QSizePolicy.Expanding,QSizePolicy.Minimum)
        self.horizontalLayout_10.addItem(spacerItem7)
        self.verticalLayout_3.addLayout(self.horizontalLayout_10)
        self.horizontalLayout_5 = QHBoxLayout()
        #self.horizontalLayout_5.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("horizontalLayout_5"))
        self.etiqueta8 = QLabel(self.frame8)
        #self.etiqueta8.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("etiqueta8"))
        self.horizontalLayout_5.addWidget(self.etiqueta8)
        self.lineEdit3 = QLineEdit(self.frame8)
        self.lineEdit3.setMaximumSize(QSize(90, 16777215))
        #self.lineEdit3.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("lineEdit3"))
        self.horizontalLayout_5.addWidget(self.lineEdit3)
        self.etiqueta9 = QLabel(self.frame8)
        #self.etiqueta9.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("etiqueta9"))
        self.horizontalLayout_5.addWidget(self.etiqueta9)
        self.verticalLayout_3.addLayout(self.horizontalLayout_5)
        self.horizontalLayout_6 = QHBoxLayout()
        #self.horizontalLayout_6.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("horizontalLayout_6"))
        self.etiqueta10 = QLabel(self.frame8)
        #self.etiqueta10.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("etiqueta10"))
        self.horizontalLayout_6.addWidget(self.etiqueta10)
        self.lineEdit4 = QLineEdit(self.frame8)
        self.lineEdit4.setMaximumSize(QSize(90, 16777215))
        #self.lineEdit4.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("lineEdit4"))
        self.horizontalLayout_6.addWidget(self.lineEdit4)
        self.etiqueta11 = QLabel(self.frame8)
        #self.etiqueta11.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("etiqueta11"))
        self.horizontalLayout_6.addWidget(self.etiqueta11)
        self.verticalLayout_3.addLayout(self.horizontalLayout_6)
        self.horizontalLayout_7 = QHBoxLayout()
        #self.horizontalLayout_7.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("horizontalLayout_7"))
        self.etiqueta12 = QLabel(self.frame8)
        #self.etiqueta12.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("etiqueta12"))
        self.horizontalLayout_7.addWidget(self.etiqueta12)
        self.lineEdit5 = QLineEdit(self.frame8)
        self.lineEdit5.setMaximumSize(QSize(90, 16777215))
        #self.lineEdit5.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("lineEdit5"))
        self.horizontalLayout_7.addWidget(self.lineEdit5)
        self.etiqueta13 = QLabel(self.frame8)
        #self.etiqueta13.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("etiqueta13"))
        self.horizontalLayout_7.addWidget(self.etiqueta13)
        self.verticalLayout_3.addLayout(self.horizontalLayout_7)
        self.horizontalLayout_8 = QHBoxLayout()
        #self.horizontalLayout_8.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("horizontalLayout_8"))
        self.etiqueta14 = QLabel(self.frame8)
        #self.etiqueta14.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("etiqueta14"))
        self.horizontalLayout_8.addWidget(self.etiqueta14)
        self.lineEdit6 = QLineEdit(self.frame8)
        self.lineEdit6.setMaximumSize(QSize(90, 16777215))
        #self.lineEdit6.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("lineEdit6"))
        self.horizontalLayout_8.addWidget(self.lineEdit6)
        self.etiqueta15 = QLabel(self.frame8)
        #self.etiqueta15.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("etiqueta15"))
        self.horizontalLayout_8.addWidget(self.etiqueta15)
        self.verticalLayout_3.addLayout(self.horizontalLayout_8)
        self.verticalLayout_5.addLayout(self.verticalLayout_3)
        spacerItem8 = QSpacerItem(20, 13, QSizePolicy.Minimum,QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        self.verticalLayout_5.addItem(spacerItem8)
        self.verticalLayout_7 = QVBoxLayout()
        #self.verticalLayout_7.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("verticalLayout_7"))
        self.horizontalLayout_14 = QHBoxLayout()
        #self.horizontalLayout_14.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("horizontalLayout_14"))
        spacerItem9 = QSpacerItem(40, 20, QSizePolicy.Expanding,QSizePolicy.Minimum)
        self.horizontalLayout_14.addItem(spacerItem9)
        self.boton1 = QPushButton(self.frame8)
        #self.boton1.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("boton1"))
        self.horizontalLayout_14.addWidget(self.boton1)
        spacerItem10 = QSpacerItem(40, 20, QSizePolicy.Expanding,QSizePolicy.Minimum)
        self.horizontalLayout_14.addItem(spacerItem10)
        self.verticalLayout_7.addLayout(self.horizontalLayout_14)
        self.horizontalLayout_15 = QHBoxLayout()
        #self.horizontalLayout_15.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("horizontalLayout_15"))
        spacerItem11 = QSpacerItem(40, 20, QSizePolicy.Expanding,QSizePolicy.Minimum)
        self.horizontalLayout_15.addItem(spacerItem11)
        self.boton2 = QPushButton(self.frame8)
        #self.boton2.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("boton2"))
        self.horizontalLayout_15.addWidget(self.boton2)    
        spacerItem12 = QSpacerItem(40, 20, QSizePolicy.Expanding,QSizePolicy.Minimum)
        self.horizontalLayout_15.addItem(spacerItem12)
        self.verticalLayout_7.addLayout(self.horizontalLayout_15)
        self.verticalLayout_5.addLayout(self.verticalLayout_7)   
        spacerItem13 = QSpacerItem(20, 18, QSizePolicy.Minimum,QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        self.verticalLayout_5.addItem(spacerItem13)


        if self.band1==True and self.band2==False :

            self.etiqueta2.setText("Carga Conectada")#tenia un problema para guardar
            self.etiqueta3.setText("R")#solucione, al copiar textualmente cada linea de estos setText
            self.etiqueta4.setText("a")
            self.etiqueta5.setText("X")
            self.etiqueta6.setText("a")
            self.etiqueta7.setText("Parametros de las lineas")#si coloco acentos el programa se cuelga
            self.etiqueta8.setText("Zo1")
            self.etiqueta9.setText("a")
            self.etiqueta10.setText("Zo2")
            self.etiqueta11.setText("a")
            self.etiqueta12.setText("f")
            self.etiqueta13.setText("MHz").o so
            self.etiqueta14.setText("Vf")
            self.etiqueta15.setText("%C")
            self.boton1.setText('Calcular')
            self.boton2.setText('Ayuda')
            print('Impedancia')

        elif self.band1==False and self.band2==True :

            self.etiqueta2.setText("Carga Conectada")#tenia un problema para guardar
            self.etiqueta3.setText("G")#solucione, al copiar textualmente cada linea de estos setText
            self.etiqueta4.setText("a")
            self.etiqueta5.setText("B")
            self.etiqueta6.setText("a")
            self.etiqueta7.setText("Parametros de las lineas")#si coloco acentos el programa se cuelga
            self.etiqueta8.setText("Yo1")
            self.etiqueta9.setText("a")
            self.etiqueta10.setText("Yo2")
            self.etiqueta11.setText("a")
            self.etiqueta12.setText("f")
            self.etiqueta13.setText("MHz")
            self.etiqueta14.setText("Vf")
            self.etiqueta15.setText("%C")
            self.boton1.setText('Calcular')
            self.boton2.setText('Ayuda')
            print('Admitancia')

        return self.frame8#sin esta linea, el show() invocado en el llamarimpedancia sera desconocido    

if __name__=="__main__": 
    app=QApplication(sys.argv)
    myapp=stub1()
    myapp.show()
    app.exec_()
    #sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Por favor, añade una descripción e información adicional a la pregunta (p.e.: ¿cuál es el error?¿cuál es el resultado esperado?)

Comment: Listo Sr. Montoro agregue la descripción.

Answer (score 1):

Seria bueno que des un ejemplo mas pequeño yo te escribo un ejemplo sencillo en el que se sobre escribe la etiqueta al presionar un boton o un radio boton

Primer archivo con las configuraciones de los botones y ventana se llama etiquetas

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui

try:
    _fromUtf8 = QtCore.QString.fromUtf8
except AttributeError:
    def _fromUtf8(s):
        return s

try:
    _encoding = QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8
    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
        return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig, _encoding)
except AttributeError:
    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
        return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig)

class Ui_Dialog(object):
    def setupUi(self, Dialog):
        Dialog.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("Dialog"))
        Dialog.resize(413, 243)
        self.pushButton = QtGui.QPushButton(Dialog)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(160, 140, 75, 23))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("pushButton"))
        self.radioButton = QtGui.QRadioButton(Dialog)
        self.radioButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(90, 100, 82, 17))
        self.radioButton.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("radioButton"))
        self.radioButton_2 = QtGui.QRadioButton(Dialog)
        self.radioButton_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(220, 100, 82, 17))
        self.radioButton_2.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("radioButton_2"))
        self.label = QtGui.QLabel(Dialog)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(100, 30, 171, 31))
        self.label.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("label"))

        self.retranslateUi(Dialog)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Dialog)

    def retranslateUi(self, Dialog):
        Dialog.setWindowTitle(_translate("Dialog", "Dialog", None))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("Dialog", "PushButton", None))
        self.radioButton.setText(_translate("Dialog", "RadioButton", None))
        self.radioButton_2.setText(_translate("Dialog", "RadioButton", None))
        self.label.setText(_translate("Dialog", "HOla mundo", None))
```

Segundo archivo que importa al archivo etiquetas se llama labels

```
#Created on Thu Sep 01 21:57:06 2016

#author: Gabriel Asqui


import sys

from PyQt4 import QtGui,QtCore
from etiquetas import Ui_Dialog

class MiFormulario(QtGui.QDialog):
    def __init__(self,parent=None):  
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self,parent)
        self.ui=Ui_Dialog()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        #conectamos las señales con los eventos---------------------------
        QtCore.QObject.connect(self.ui.radioButton, QtCore.SIGNAL('isChecked()'), self.cambiar1)
        QtCore.QObject.connect(self.ui.radioButton_2, QtCore.SIGNAL('isChecked()'), self.cambiar2)
        QtCore.QObject.connect(self.ui.pushButton, QtCore.SIGNAL('clicked()'), self.cambiar3)
        #definimos los eventos--------
    def cambiar1(self):
        self.ui.label.setText('Miau')
    def cambiar2(self):
        self.ui.label.setText('Guau')
    def cambiar3(self):
        self.ui.label.setText('Pio pio')

if __name__=="__main__": 
    app=0 #previene que el nucleo muera y tener que reiniciarlo cada vez
    app=QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    myapp=MiFormulario()
    myapp.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Los dos archivos créalos en el mismo directorio y corre el archivo labels.
Saludos

Answer (score 1):

Facilita las cosas, en vez de andar buscando directamente tu widget dado que estás trabajando específicamente con un sólo label en este caso.

En el primer archivo `class Ui_dialog` define:

```
def setText(str)
   self.label.setText(str)
```

y desde el archivo principal

```
def cambiar1(self):
        self.ui.setText('Miau')
    def cambiar2(self):
        self.ui.setText('Guau')
    def cambiar3(self):
        self.ui.setText('Pio pio')
```

Comment: Gracias Mariano por la corrección, tratare de cuidar la ortografía :)